# create for loop in R to run same model for 10 times

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a loop in R after imputation. The imputation imputed 10 data sets and I want to run the same model in each data set and predict score of outcome in each data set. My current code does not work:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
impi <- glm(died ~ agecat + female_1 + insurance + mech + transfer +
            iss + mxaisbr1 + maxais + cm_chf_1 + cm_mets_1 + cm_liver_1 +
            cm_htn_c_1 + cm_bldloss_1 + state, data = subset(imp, .imp == i), family = binomial)
preimpi <- predict(impi, type = c('response'))
}
```

Without the loop, I have to type the same code for 10 times

```
imp1 <- glm(died ~ agecat + female_1 + insurance + mech + transfer +
            iss + mxaisbr1 + maxais + cm_chf_1 + cm_mets_1 + cm_liver_1 +
            cm_htn_c_1 + cm_bldloss_1 + state, data = subset(imp, .imp == 1), family = binomial)
preimp1 <- prediect(imp1, type = c('response'))
imp2 <- glm(died ~ agecat + female_1 + insurance + mech + transfer +
            iss + mxaisbr1 + maxais + cm_chf_1 + cm_mets_1 + cm_liver_1 +
            cm_htn_c_1 + cm_bldloss_1 + state, data = subset(imp, .imp == 2), family = binomial)
preimp2 <- prediect(imp2, type = c('response'))
etc...
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: The most efficient way to do this is by creating a list of datasets (your 10 datasets) and run the model for each dataset, using the `dplyr` and `purrr` packages. You can find some info here: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups

Comment: However, there's nothing wrong with the for loop. It looks like you overwrite `preimpi` at each iteration.

Comment: Thanks! do you know how can I not overwrite preimpi? the output from my for loop code is impi and preimpi instead of imp1-imp10 and preimp1-preimp10 as I wanted.

Comment: I think you need to first create a set of empty values to store the results:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to initialize impi and preimpi as lists, e.g.,

```
impi = list()
preimpi = list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  impi[[i]] <- glm(died ~ agecat + female_1 + insurance + mech +
               transfer + iss + mxaisbr1 + maxais + cm_chf_1 + 
               cm_mets_1 + cm_liver_1 + cm_htn_c_1 + cm_bldloss_1 +
               state, data = subset(imp, .imp == i), family = binomial)
  preimpi[[i]] <- predict(impi[[i]], type = c('response'))
}
```

Note the use of double brackets for indexing a list.

Edit: Here is an alternative that uses lapply for the predict line, which should produce the same output as the example above.

```
impi = list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  impi[[i]] <- glm(died ~ agecat + female_1 + insurance + mech +
               transfer + iss + mxaisbr1 + maxais + cm_chf_1 + 
               cm_mets_1 + cm_liver_1 + cm_htn_c_1 + cm_bldloss_1 +
               state, data = subset(imp, .imp == i), family = binomial)
}
preimpi = lapply(impi, FUN = predict, type = "response")
```